# Colored emoji in VS Code Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-7, emoji

I'm trying desperately to display the colored emoji in VS Code but it's impossible. I am using Windows 7 and the emoji appear in black and white.

I tried the Emoji extension (support for Windows 7) but it's even worse because the emoji disappear.

Isn't there a simple solution to do this? Maybe there is a font problem but my emoji appear in color in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 does not have colour font support. That was added in Windows 8.1.

Note that Windows 7 is no longer supported by Microsoft, as of January 2020: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information